# SQL Query to check if a timeblock already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Searched a lot and found a lot, And came up with a query that works but is a little slow.

What i want to check is the the following condition:

I have a table with appointments with `StartTime` and `EndTime`. When I insert a new appointment there is currently no check if there is already some kind of appointment in the specified `timerange`. For example, I want to insert an appointment with a `timeblock` from 09:00 - 09:30 but there is already an appointment from 09:15 - 09:30 then i need to return that specific appointment by a query. Also overlapping blocks and whole blocks needs to be returned. So actually every appointment that touches each other needs to be returned.

The query I have now is the following:

```
SELECT * from dbo.Appointments
WHERE 
(('2017-09-26 09:00:00' > StartTime AND '2017-09-26 09:00:00' < EndTime) 
OR 
('2017-09-26 09:30:00' > StartTime AND '2017-09-26 09:30:00' < EndTime) 
OR 
(StartTime BETWEEN '2017-09-26 09:00:00' AND '2017-09-26 09:30:00'))
```

This will return every appointment that is overlapping or in the range of the new appointment but it is kind of slow.

Is there some other `query` to check it in one SELECT or is this `OR` `OR` statement the only solution?

Comment: Check OVERLAPS predicate!

Comment: Do you have indexes on `StartTime` and `EndTime`?

Comment: I have indexes on AppointmentID not on StartTime and EndTime, I'll check that one

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I use MSSQL Server and Management Studio 2014

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely need indexes on `StartTime` and `EndTime` if you want your SQL to run fast. Moreover, I guess the following query would do what you need as well and it is more subtle

```
SELECT * from dbo.Appointments
WHERE EndTime > '2017-09-26 09:00:00' AND StartTime < '2017-09-26 09:30:00'
```

Comment: I think it should be `AND` not `OR`, no?

Comment: @sami he needs the appointment if it overlaps, therefore, only one of the attributes can be in the interval to satisfy such requirement.

Comment: Radim, This query is nice indeed for overlaps but I also need to get appointmentsback that fall inside the range. Example the query above does not return an appointment that is from 08:00 till 11:00. It will now only return appointments that are between 09:00 and 09:30 which is not what i want to achieve. I literally need ALL appointments that touches the other one. See this screenshot for example: [See screenshot of my idea in Excel](https://prnt.sc/gpsy7t)

Comment: @JoeyErdogan you are right, I forgot about this situation. Please see the edit, is it correct now?

Comment: @RadimBača This did the trick :) You are a hero! thank you very much

Comment: @JoeyErdogan I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Use **BETWEEN** in SQL while comparing two dates. Don't use > or <

Comment: You mean where '2017-09-26 09:00:00' BETWEEN StartTime and EndTime